Can the soft body LENGTH option be animated?
According to the manual and this video one can use the length option to shrink or expand a soft body:
Length option: Soft body physics > Edges > Length
Youtube movie:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lqUxQ2XN4o

This option does work if you change the value at frame 1.
However, if you use keyframes to change the value during an animation then it doesn't work.
Looks like a bug as you can set a keyframe for this option...?
My testfile:

Thx!

Your test file is locked so is impossible to access. If it's under 30Meg in size you should share it through the official web site at https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Test file added to blend-exchange!
